# Can not remove dynamically added widget in kivy layout

Tags: widget, kivy

Depending whether content exists or not I want to either display the content list or just an image. So I have in the init cycle:

```
self.instrresults.imgwgt = None
```

Each second a cycle runs looking for content. If the content container is empty then lgr == 0 and I am adding the Image widget. When in the next cycle, the content container is full, I want to remove the Image widget and show the content in a ListView. In principle this works fine except that the Image widget is not removed. Instead, new Image widgets are added. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help in advance.

```
if lgr == 0:
    if not self.instrresults.imgwgt:
        self.imgwgt = Image(id='nocontent_img', center_y=self.parent.center_y, stretch=True,
                            x=self.parent.x, size=self.parent.size, source='./images/nocontent.png')
        self.instrresults.add_widget(self.imgwgt)
else:
    if self.instrresults.imgwgt: self.remove_widget(self.instrresults.imgwgt)
```

The kv file shows as follows:

```
BoxLayout:
    TabbedPanel:
        id: typeselector
        do_default_tab: False
        background_image: ""
        background_color: 1,1,1,1
        tab_width: dp(self.width / 4)

        TabbedPanelItem:
            id: tabinstr
            font_size: '12sp'
            color: .3,.3,.3,1
            size: self.texture_size
            halign: 'right'
            valign: 'top'

            BoxLayout:
                id: instrresults
                orientation: "vertical"
                ScrollView:
                    ListView:
                        id: search_results_list
                        adapter: root.adapterin or self.adapter
```

**EDIT**
When testing the situation as follows, the widgets are being added but never removed. I can't find the clue.

```
for child in self.instrresults.children[:]:
    self.remove_widget(child)
    print "child:", child
print "-------------------"
lgr = len(guideresult)
if lgr == 0:
    self.imgwgt = Image(id='nocontent_img', center_y=self.parent.center_y, stretch=True,
                            x=self.parent.x, size=self.parent.size, source='./images/nocontent.png')
    self.instrresults.add_widget(self.imgwgt)
self.adapterin.data[:] = guideresult
```

and the output shows that widgets are being added but never removed:

```
child <kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView object at 0x0ECAECE0>
-------------------
child <kivy.uix.image.Image object at 0x0F73A180>
child <kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView object at 0x0ECAECE0>
-------------------
child <kivy.uix.image.Image object at 0x0F73A180>
child <kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView object at 0x0ECAECE0>
-------------------
child <kivy.uix.image.Image object at 0x1008B110>
child <kivy.uix.image.Image object at 0x0F73A180>
child <kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView object at 0x0ECAECE0>
-------------------
child <kivy.uix.image.Image object at 0x1008B110>
child <kivy.uix.image.Image object at 0x0F73A180>
child <kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView object at 0x0ECAECE0>
-------------------
```

**SOLUTION**

```
for child in self.instrresults.children[:]:
    if child.id == 'nocontent_img': self.instrresults.remove_widget(child)
lgr = len(guideresult)
if lgr == 0:
    self.imgwgt = Image(id='nocontent_img', source='./images/nocontent.png')
    self.instrresults.add_widget(self.imgwgt)
```

Comment: You assign to `self.imgwgt` but you check `self.intrresults.imgwgt`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately the result stays the same. I have added some testcode and results. See EDIT.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self.instrresults.remove_widget(child)`?

Comment: Hi FJSevilla, this sure was the golden tip. But to avoid removing all the widgets I had to add a condition to test on the widget id of the child. See final code under the Solution header in the original message. Thanks for your help.